# How to draw/animate transparent images/objects over a video in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, vlc, qframe

I created a media player application using `python-vlc` and `PyQt5`, quite similar to [this qtvlc code](https://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob_plain;f=examples/qtvlc.py).
A minimal reproducible code is shown as follows:

```py
class Player(QMainWindow):
    """A simple Media Player using VLC and Qt
    """
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, master)
        self.setWindowTitle("Media Player")

        # creating a basic vlc instance
        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        # creating an empty vlc media player
        self.mediaplayer = self.instance.media_player_new()

        self.createUI()
        self.isPaused = False

    def createUI(self):
        """Set up the user interface, signals & slots
        """
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        self.videoframe = QFrame()
        self.videoframe.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        pixmap.load("path to transparent_image.png")
        self.my_label = QLabel(self)
        self.my_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.my_label.setGeometry(300, 250, 100, 100)
        self.my_label.setFrameStyle(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.my_label.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.vboxlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vboxlayout.addWidget(self.videoframe)

        self.widget.setLayout(self.vboxlayout)

        self.media = self.instance.media_new("path to video file")
        # put the media in the media player
        self.mediaplayer.set_media(self.media)

        # the media player has to be 'connected' to the QFrame
        # (otherwise a video would be displayed in it's own window)
        # this is platform specific!
        # you have to give the id of the QFrame (or similar object) to
        # vlc, different platforms have different functions for this
        if sys.platform.startswith('linux'): # for Linux using the X Server
            self.mediaplayer.set_xwindow(self.videoframe.winId())
        elif sys.platform == "win32": # for Windows
            self.mediaplayer.set_hwnd(self.videoframe.winId())
        elif sys.platform == "darwin": # for MacOS
            self.mediaplayer.set_nsobject(self.videoframe.winId())
        self.mediaplayer.play()

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = Player()
    player.show()
    player.resize(640, 480)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Once I run the code, I can see that the transparent image is drawn on top of the video but the image instead of showing the background video through it continues to show the portion of the `QFrame` as its background. Can anyone help me with getting around this issue?

Comment: please provide a  [mre]

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, I have updated the question, which now includes a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).